# Generate permutations of list by swapping specific elements

Tags: python, list, combinations, permutation, cartesian-product

I'm trying to write a function that generates all possible configurations of a list by swapping certain allowable pairs of elements.

For example, if we have the list:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

And we only allow the swapping of the following pairs of elements:

```
pairs = [[0, 2], [4, 1]]
```

i.e., we can only swap the 0th element if the list with the 2nd, and the 4th element with the 1st (there can be any number of allowed pairs of swaps).
I would like the function to return the number of distinct configurations of the list given the allowable swaps.

Since I'm planning on running this for large lists and many allowable swaps, it would be preferable for the function to be as efficient as possible.

I've found examples that generate permutations by swapping all the elements, two at a time, but I can't find a way to specify certain pairs of allowable swaps.

Answer (score 1):

You've been lured off other productive paths by the common term "swap".  Switch your attack.  Instead, note that you need the product of [a[0], a[2]] and [a[1], a[4]] to get all the possible permutations.  You take each of these products (four of them) and distribute the elements in your result sets in the proper sequence.  It will look vaguely like this ... I'm using Python as pseudo-code, to some extent.

```
seq = itertools.product([a[0], a[2]], [a[1], a[4]])
for soln in seq:
    # each solution "soln" is a list of 4 elements to be distributed.
    # Construct a permutation "b" by putting each in its proper place.
    # Map the first two soln values to b[0] and b[2];
    # and the last two values to b[1] and b[4]
    b = [soln[0], soln[2], soln[1], a[3], soln[4]]
```

Can you take it from there?  That's the idea; I'll leave you to generalize the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I print `soln` in the for loop it's a list of two numbers instead of 4. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, I'm missing something -- that should be the permutations of (a[0], a[2]) crossed with (product) the permutations of (a[1], a[4]).  On my way oout the door, or I'd fix the pseudo-code and test it.